# Indication if Database is updated

Tags: jsp, backend

I am making a JSP page and I am uploading data to database and when the data is completely loaded, I want my JSP page to show an indication that data has been loaded. How to go about that?

Comment: Are you loading the data to the DB from your JSP page, or some other way?

Comment: You require reverse-ajax for something like that. If the same method which you are using in JSP is loading the data in database, then you just require a redirection.

Comment: no, the Data is being uploaded onto the DB by another program, my page refreshes to show the changes in the DB too. I have an icon thats red when no changes have been made, and when the changes are made it turns green, how would I go about implementing that ? I read someplace I could do it with JScript, but I'm not sure exactly how to go about it ...